# Rails 5 - polymorphic attachment with dynamic styles using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to have a polymorphic attachment class with dynamic styles using paperclip and use it form another class(Foo).

I have the Attachment class:

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true, optional: true

  has_attached_file :attachment,
    styles: ->(a) {a.instance.attachable.attachment_styles}

  validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

And the Foo class:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attachments, class_name: "Attachment", as: :attachable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments

  def attachment_styles
    {
     :thumb => "30x30>",
     :medium => "100x100>"
    }
  end
end
```

The problem here is that I don't have the foo object yet, inside that lambda function. `a.instance.attachable` returns nil.

The error I'm getting is:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `attachment_styles' for nil:NilClass
```

I am using Rails 5 and paperclip 5.0.0. 
I think this worked with Rails 4.

PS: I need the style to be dynamic because I will use the attachment from multiple models, not just from Foo.